# Detect the shortest word in a sentence in C

Tags: c

I have created the below program to detect the shortest word in a sentence for me. However, the result is not what I expected. I went through the code a few times and I still could not find the problem.

I would be very grateful if someone could lend me some help.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

ssize_t find_short(const char *s);

int main(void)
{
    char s[100] ="lets talk about C the best language";
    printf("%zu", find_short(s));
}

ssize_t find_short(const char *s)
{
    int n = strlen(s);
    int smallest = n;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\0')
        {
            if (counter <= smallest)
            {
            smallest = (ssize_t) counter;
            counter = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        counter ++;
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: How is it not what you expected? What is the expected result? What is the actual result? Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement (while monitoring variables and their values) in a debugger? What does that tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reset `counter` only when `counter` is smallest than `smallest`. If a new word is shorter than any previous, it will be ignored.

```
ssize_t find_short(const char *s)
{
    int n = strlen(s);
    int smallest = n;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\0')
        {
            if (counter <= smallest)
            {
                smallest = (ssize_t) counter;
                // <-- not here
            }
            counter = 0;  //  < -- here
        }
        else
            counter ++;
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`counter=0` should be outside the if statement

```
ssize_t find_short(const char *s)
{
    int n = strlen(s);
    int smallest = n;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\0')
        {
            if (counter <= smallest)
            {
            smallest = (ssize_t) counter;

            }
            counter = 0;
        }
        else
        counter ++;
    }
    return smallest;
}
```